# VBA code skipping entire section, the code works separately but not when combined

Tags: excel, vba

So the code is two parts.

Part A) Open a the folder directory and when you click OK. It Runs the Code of Part B. Then saves the file, and finally outputs a msg box.

Part B) It runs the code on the file.

Hypothesis: That 2 lines of code is the reason why it does not work. I believe the first is initiating the code to run and second is this    `Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("report123")`

Here is the entire code

```
Public Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim myPath As String
Dim myFile As String
Dim myExtension As String
Dim FldrPicker As FileDialog

'Optimize Macro Speed
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Application.EnableEvents = False
  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

'Retrieve Target Folder Path From User
  Set FldrPicker = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

    With FldrPicker
      .Title = "Select A Target Folder"
      .AllowMultiSelect = False
        If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
        myPath = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
    End With

'In Case of Cancel
NextCode:
  myPath = myPath
  If myPath = "" Then GoTo ResetSettings

'Target File Extension (must include wildcard "*")
  myExtension = "*.xlsx"

'Target Path with Ending Extention
  myFile = Dir(myPath & myExtension)

'Loop through each Excel file in folder
  Do While myFile <> ""
    'Set variable equal to opened workbook
      Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=myPath & myFile)

    'Ensure Workbook has opened before moving on to next line of code
      DoEvents
```

My Code for the file starts here

```
ActiveSheet.Columns("A").Insert Shift:=xlToRight

ActiveSheet.Columns("A").Insert Shift:=xlToLeft


Range("A1").Value = "Source 2"

Range("B1").Value = "BU ID"

    Columns("I").Replace What:="eas", _
                            Replacement:="reC", _
                            LookAt:=xlPart, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                            MatchCase:=False, _
                            SearchFormat:=False, _
                            ReplaceFormat:=False



Dim arrData As Variant, LastRow As Long, i As Long, ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("report123")
    With ws
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
        arrData = .Range("A2", .Cells(LastRow, "C")).Value
        For i = 1 To UBound(arrData)
            If arrData(i, 3) Like "Bus*" Then
                arrData(i, 1) = "BU CRM"
            Else
                arrData(i, 1) = "CSI ACE"
            End If
            If arrData(i, 3) Like "CSI*" Or arrData(i, 3) = vbNullString Then
                arrData(i, 2) = vbNullString
            Else
                arrData(i, 2) = Right(arrData(i, 3), Len(arrData(i, 3)) - 12)
            End If
        Next i
        .Range("A2", .Cells(LastRow, "C")).Value = arrData
    End With
```

My Code for the file ends here

```
    wb.Close SaveChanges:=True


      DoEvents


      myFile = Dir
  Loop


  MsgBox "Task Complete!"

ResetSettings:

    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried to debug the code step by step (F8) to see what fails?

Comment: A consistent but likely unrelated flaw in your code is that you're not referring to a specific wb/ws (e.g. with `Range("A1")`) which can cause errors.

Comment: As FunThomas said - go line by line and see what exactly happens inside. Apart from that: don't do stuff with `Activesheet`, you can never be 100% sure which sheet is active. Say explicitly which sheet of which workbook you need. Instead of `ActiveSheet.Columns("A").Insert Shift:=xlToRight` do (if you want to work the first sheet: `wb.sheets(1).Columns("A").Insert Shift:=xlToRight` or if you want to choose sheet by name `wb.sheets("Some worksheet name").Columns("A").Insert Shift:=xlToRight`

Comment: Endorsing @MKaras  comments further instead of  `Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("report123")` use `Set ws = wb.Sheets("report123")`

Comment: @MKaras Your observations are valid. If you feel it alright you can put it as an answer also to close the question.

Comment: @FunThomas I have used the F8 button and looked step by step. I have yet to approach a solution sadly. The code runs until (Do While MyFiles " ") and then skips to (MsgBox "Task Complete")

Comment: That means that your `Dir`-command doesn't find anything. Check the exact content of the variables `myPath` and  `myExtension`.

Comment: Dir returns nothing only if the provided path doesn't exist, so as @FunThomas said, you have to inspect your myPath variable. Put a breakpoint on line `Do While myFile <> ""` or press F8 until you get to this line. Then in your Immediate Window (View -> Immediate Window if you don't see it) type `?myPath & myExtension` and press enter. It will print the path in the immediate window. Check if this path is correct and if you can actually find the file using this path. By the way, I recommend doing a full VBA debugging tutorial, maybe this one: https://www.wiseowl.co.uk/blog/s196/debugging.htm